# Using Query or Code

Tags: c#, .net

I have been reading about queries, lambda and coding in .NET C#. As of now I am writing code without queries and without lambdas, but every time I use Lists, I could write the queries in at least three different ways.

Is it preferable to retrieve data from lists and arrays trough a query/lambda or trough a loop like in classical programming?

Query Example:

```
int searchedNumber = 5;
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,0};

var result = from n in numbers
                             where n == searchedNumber
                             select n;
```

Or a Loop. Example:

```
int searchedNumber = 5;
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
int result = 0;

foreach(int n in numbers)
{
     if(searchedNumber == n)
     {
          result = n;
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: "Preferable" to whom?  There are lots of ways to accomplish the same task.  As long as the code is clear and concise and performs as needed, what's the difference if not one of personal preference?

Comment: Preferable is vague. Preferable for performance?, for clarity reading?, for the ease of mind of your project leader? Please explain.

Comment: Whatever you do... be consistent. There is nothing worse than looking through a codebase that mixes styles.

Comment: I would do it like `int result =numbers.FirstOrDefault(x=> x== searchedNumber);` side note, your two implementations not doing the same

Comment: `bool there = numbers.Contains(5);`

Comment: Generally speaking I recommend using LINQ for querying and using a ForEach when you want to manipulate data (especially if it's a complex manipulation).

Answer (score 2):

The choice is yours, but you should consider a couple of things.

First: **favor readability**. Whatever you/your team consider readable and easy to process with a quick glance is fine. If you all process query syntax easier, stick to that. If you all prefer method syntax, use that! If you all hate LINQ, manually loop.

Second: **be consistent**. The above point is useless if the style changes 30 times within the same class. Pick one and stick with it.

Other than that: if you are really feeling like being premature-optimization, then you can consider the extra object allocations that come with Lambdas and LINQ queries and favor manually looping.
This is only if you really care about tiny amounts of extra memory allocations (which you should only care about, if you have profiled your code and can prove it is a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are great, but when they're becomming to complex it's better to mix them with clasic loop statements.

in your example I would write:

```
numbers.FirstOrDefault(number => number == searchedNumber);
```

as you see, i prefer fluent style linq.
But if for you more clarity is
    from n in numbers where n == searchedNumber select n;
why not.

But

```
SomeData.Where(visit => ids.Contains(visit.Id))
                .ToDictionary(visit => visit.Id, visit =>
                {
                    var visit = visit.NewVisit;
                    bool isEwusCheck = visit.Patient.EwusChecks.Any(
                        check =>
                            check.X_RemoveTime == null && check.IsInsured);

                    bool isEuDocument = visit.Patient.EuPatientDocuments.Any(
                        document =>
                            document.ValidFrom.Date <= visit.StartTime.Date &&
                            document.ValidTo.Date >= visit.StartTime.Date);

                    bool isDeclatarion =
                        visit.Patient.Documents.Any(
                            document =>
                                document.PatientDocumentType.IsDocumentDeclaration &&
                                document.ValidFrom.Date <= visit.StartTime.Date &&
                                document.ValidTo.Date >= visit.StartTime.Date);

                    return new NfzPatientInsuranceInfoModel(visit.PatientId, isEwusCheck || isEuDocument || isDeclatarion, isEuDocument);
                });
```

is not very elegant and code is not as readable as it could be - so you could think about use classic loop statements.

Comment: This code is not that bad. It calculates all three bools always, which is inefficient, and it overrides `visit` variable, which may be confusing, but the rest is understandable. The same amount of time is required to understand the equivalent loop based code.

Comment: I also think it's quite understand but my point was - if yours linq is getting too complicated try to divide it into pieces or replace some parts of it with code. 
For example - If you have main .ForEach(..) and linq operating on each element, its good to change main .ForEach to foreach(){...

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume searchedNumber is actually  a parameter or at least mutable and not a const value as defined.

In the examples the first is a must.  The reason is that 0 is in your list of possible numbers so using it as a magic number won't work reliably if searchedNumber == 0. The select statement returns an IEnumerable so you can differentiate if your value was found using Any.

As stated though you'd use Contains or Any with a predicate to find out if the container contains your value.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with Steve in the comments above. But, because this seems to be a 'newbie' question...

Often solution #2 leads to mixing 'selection' logic with 'business' logic. For example:

```
//int searchedNumber = 5;
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
//int result = 0;

foreach(int n in numbers)
{
     if(n < y)
     {
          DoX(n);
     }
     else if(n > y)
     {
         DoY(n);
     }
     else
     {
         DoZ(n);
     }
}
```

Then you change your selection logic ("if"), or split one grouping into two ... and I find that you can get lost in the loop.

Instead, how about this:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,0};

// selection logic
var group1 = from n in numbers
             where n < y
             select n;

var group2 = from n in numbers
             where n > y
             select n;

// business logic
foreach(var i in group1)
    DoX(i);

foreach(var i in group2)
    DoY(i);
```

The advantages of this 'style' of coding is that:
 1. you don't have to touch your business logic code, if you change the selection logic (and vice a versa)
 2. you can clearly see what conditions constitute membership to DoX, DoY, etc.

This is similar to async programming where you have the 'task' and the 'completion'.  It is not only efficient but maintains clear separation of domains.